# Framework for Mobile Websites

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

Is there any recommended framework for developing mobile websites (NOT webapps)? I am currently using meteor for the desktop-side website and I have been suggested to use Ionic, PhoneGap & similia, but as I understood they have been made to develop mobile apps (app-store downloadable, not what I need).

I would like to use programming languages I know for website developing (HTML, CSS and JS would be perfect, not really into PHP).

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Just create css for mobile with media queries.

Comment: You don't need a framework for that. If it's just a mobile website you can do a responsive website or serve a different version when user uses a mobile (if it needs to be realy different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There is nothing like framework for Mobile Websites.Its all CSS magic.
But to make life easier you can give a try on ionic ,phonegap or cardova.


 https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/
 https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/phonegap/
```

Comment: Aren't all of them Mobile Webapp frameworks?

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.